# cassandra massive write perfomance problem

Tags: performance, cassandra

I have server with 4 GB RAM and 2x 4 cores CPU. When I start perform massive writes in Cassandra all works fine initially, but after a couple hours with 10K inserts per second database grows up to 25+ GB, and performance go down to *500 insert per seconds*!

I find out this because compacting operations is very slow but I don't understand why? I set 8 concurrent compacting threads but Cassandra don't use 8 threads; only 2 cores are loaded.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: what os are you trying this on?

Comment: if I were to take a wild guess I would say you're probably exhausting your rather small heap with so many concurrent compactions.  so start by dropping to one concurrent compaction, then update your question with this kind of information: http://spyced.blogspot.com/2010/01/linux-performance-basics.html and the lines Cassandra's StatusLogger is writing to its system.log

Answer (score 4):

We've seen similar problems with Cassandra out-the-box, see:

http://www.acunu.com/blogs/richard-low/cassandra-under-heavy-write-load-part-ii/

One solution to these sort of performance degradation issues  (but by no means the only) is to consider a different storage engine, like Castle, used in the above blog post - its opensource (GPL v2), has much better performance and degrades much more gracefully.  The code is here (I've just pushed up a branch for Cassandra 0.8 support):

https://bitbucket.org/acunu/fs.hg

And instructions on how to get started are here:

http://support.acunu.com/entries/20216797-castle-build-instructions

(Full disclosure: I work for Acunu, so may be a little biased ;-)